# Drivers for monitor lenovo y27-20q

Tags: drivers, lenovo, screen, monitor

I want to connect 2 monitors one with HDMI and one with display port, the one with the HDMI cable is a basic dell display 1920:1080 and the one with the display port has a 2K resolution. the monitor with the display port is not working, Ubuntu does see it but the screen on it is black. when I first installed Ubuntu i had only a dell display connected and it was not the one I'm using currently but the one I'm using right now still works.

I updated the Nvidia GTX 1080 drivers to the latest version I saw on the list that Ubuntu suggests and now the computer would not boot into Ubuntu and only windows works. its a lenovo legion cube and the display using the display port is a lenovo y27 - 20q display. when my computer still booted into Linux that's what was happening:
if i restart my computer with the two monitors connected to it i will just see a black screen. Ubuntu does not recognize my second monitor no matter what i do. it is just black and goes to sleep. although i see it in the monitors tab in the settings menu it does not show anything when i try to set it as my main monitor. can someone please help me manually connect the drivers to the display like we do in Windows? (device manager and then manually select drivers)

Comment: I suggest you update your original question with the version of Ubuntu you are using, the make/model of your laptop/PC, or at least the graphics hardware. And say exactly how you are connecting the two monitors to your PC (e.g. the connection on both ends of pc/monitor for both monitors, HDMI or display port etc, and say if you are using any adaptors) and post the full results of running `xrandr` in a terminal. Also what resolutions are showing as options in the Ubuntu settings? Have you tried various different resolutions?

Comment: thaks for the comment, i updated the question but can not add the xrander command output since my computer will not boot into linux